# Groovy console can't "remember" any variables - always says "unknown property"

Tags: grails, groovy, console

In the Groovy shell you can type in commands, such as

```
def x = 1
```

and run them.  That line comes back with:

```
groovy:000> > def x = 1
def x = 1
===> 1
groovy:000>
```

Now if I type:

```
 println(x)
```

I get:

```
groovy:000> > println(x)
println(x)
Unknown property: x
groovy:000>
```

So it seems that the console nor shell remembers object definitions, is this normal?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This is standard behavior in the Groovy shell, not peculiar to the Grails shell.  You probably don't want to `def` the variable.  See the following:

```
~ $ groovysh
Groovy Shell (2.3.4, JVM: 1.7.0_45)
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
groovy:000> def x = 42
===> 42
groovy:000> x
Unknown property: x
groovy:000> y = 2112
===> 2112
groovy:000> y
===> 2112
groovy:000>
```

From http://beta.groovy-lang.org/groovysh.html

> **1.3.4. Variables**
>
> Shell variables are **all** untyped (ie. no `def` or other type information).
>
> This will set a shell variable:
>
> ```
> foo = "bar"
> ```
>
> But, this will evaluate a local variable and will **not** be saved to the shell’s environment:
>
> ```
> def foo = "bar"
> ```

You can change this behaviour by enabling [interpreterMode](http://groovy-lang.org/groovysh.html#GroovyShell-InterpreterMode)

```
groovy:000> := interpreterMode
groovy:000> def x = 42
===> 42
groovy:000> x
===> 42
groovy:000>
```

Comment: Wow, this is really confusing.  Why would declaring the type in standard java way, or using def in the grails way, fail in the console, but not in the app?  I have spent an hour searching for examples showing how to use the console, including going through my 6 groovy and gails books, with not a single entry.  How did you work this one out?

Comment: "How did you work this one out?" - I worked it out because I am on the Groovy and Grails team and am familiar with how this works.

Comment: I realize that link might not be a good link in the future when folks find this answer so I should include more info here.  The docs linked above currently says the following about `def'd` variables...  "...this will evaluate a local variable and will not be saved to the shell’s environment."

Comment: That is a great link! it has everything I was looking for - nice one.

Comment: What are the valid uses for `def` then? So that you can evaluate variables without effecting the shell environment?

Comment: `:= interpreterMode` fixes the problem perfectly!! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

"def" are more like compiled variables in Java way (to some degree), compiled (maybe type is unknown/dynamic, but name/existence of variable / property is known).

`def xyz = 1` -> `Object xyz = 1;`

Without "def" are added to specific container Binder by name, in fully dynamic manner. Imagine this like specific Map *(sorry for simplicity)*

```
binder["xyz"] = 1;
```

My personal filling is that Groovy doc don't illustrate this (huge) difference clearly. Word "untyped" seems to weak. 
Implementation of "storage" for this two is totally different.